# Angular Ivy and curly brackets

Tags: angular, angular9, angular-ivy

I recently updated my app to angular 9 with Ivy compiler and I've run into this error:

> Error: Errors parsing template: Unexpected character "EOF" (Do you
>   have an unescaped "{" in your template? Use "{{ '{' }}") to escape
>   it.) ("]="{'selected': isSelected(option)}",
>       *ngFor="let option of options; index as i;"   ) {{option}}

For this template (here the pug version)

```
.MultiSelect
  .MultiSelect__message {{message}}
  .MultiSelect__option(
    (click)="toggleOption(option, $event)",
    [ngClass]="{'selected': isSelected(option)}", <-- here the error
    *ngFor="let option of options; index as i;"
  ) {{option}}
```

What is trying to tell me is that I need to replace each single `{` with `{{ '{' }}` that seems tome a odd and unreadable:

```
[ngClass]="{{ '{' }}'selected': isSelected(option){{ '}' }}"
```

So what's the point? There's something i can do to workaround this or di I really need to rewrite my code?